# what are the benefits of upgrading the domain functional level?

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server, windows-server-2016, domain-security

I have a domain in Europe, `mycompany.eu` and another domain in the USA, `mycompany.com`,

they are in a [trust relationship](http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1016-active-directory-trust-relationships/), although I don't know which one.

I noticed that the functional level of my domain in Europe is `Windows Server 2008`.

I have seen the articles below, but still, what are the benefits of upgrading the domain functional level?

[What is the Impact of Upgrading the Domain or Forest Functional Level?](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/archive/blogs/askds/what-is-the-impact-of-upgrading-the-domain-or-forest-functional-level)

[What Are Active Directory Functional Levels?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc787290(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[image: hare krishna]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading the domain or the forest functional level introduces new features that were added in to AD DS in newer versions of Windows Server. For example, on the domain functional level, Server 2008 introduced the ability to log users' last interactive login information. In the forest functional level, Server 2008 R2 added the Active Directory Recycle Bin.

It's up to you whether your organization needs the newer features that the newer functional levels have to offer. I was able to find a site with a list of benefits/changes to each functional level:

- [Forest Functional Levels (FFL)](https://www.windows-active-directory.com/forest-functional-level.html)
- [Domain Functional Levels (DFL)](https://www.windows-active-directory.com/domain-functional-level.html)